# How to Query the Google Cloud Vision API with a local image using python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, google-vision

I want to send a request to the Google vision API, using an Locally stored Image.
Im following the "[Python Client for Google Cloud Vision¶](https://googleapis.dev/python/vision/latest/index.html)" guide, exspecialy the code example under "Annotage an Image".
For building my request I follow the example from "[Base64 Encoding](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/base64)".

Here is the code I wrote:

```
from google.cloud.vision import ImageAnnotatorClient
import os
import base64
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'keys/sc_google.json'

def encode_image(image_path):
    with open(image_path, "rb") as f:
        image_content = f.read()
        return base64.b64encode(image_content)

client = ImageAnnotatorClient()
image_path = 'images/happy_baby3.png'
query = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "image": {
                "content": encode_image(image_path)
            },
            "features": [
                {
                    "type": "FACE_DETECTION",
                    "maxResults": 10
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
response = client.annotate_image(query)
print(response.annotations)
```

Stil wenn running the code I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/Users/nomis/PycharmProjects/hello_web_app/emotion_detection.py", line 29, in <module>
    response = client.annotate_image(query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/cloud/vision_helpers/__init__.py", line 55, in annotate_image
    image = protobuf.get(request, "image")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/api_core/protobuf_helpers.py", line 192, in get
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'image'
```

I also tried [this Example](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/libraries) but got the error "Can not find Reference 'Image' in 'types.py'.

Could you explain what I'm doing wrong, and provide a minimal working example of how to query the Google Vision API using a local Image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the example you linked, there is no array of requests. Try this:

```
query = {
            "image": {
                "content": encode_image(image_path)
            },
            "features": [
                {
                    "type": "FACE_DETECTION",
                    "maxResults": 10
                }
            ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
With that change I was able make it work.

This is the resource I found that provides a minimal working excample:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45695542/google-cloud-vision-not-accepting-base64-encoded-images-python/45696640)